# Grouping Silverlight chart ColumnSeries

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit

As the title states, I want to group some ColumnSeries, I'm using Silverlight Charting Toolkit.

**Here is an image to explain what I want:**

[image: Demonstrating ColunSeries Grouping]

but in my case, **the ColumnSerieses are always stuck together.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chart you have included seems to be a fairly straightforward affair.  Its exactly what ColumnSeries is designed to generate.

A set of 4 `ColumnSeries` one for each quarter and a `DateTimeAxis` with and interval type of Years and an interval of 1.

I suspect there is actually more to your question because this just seems too simple otherwise?